# Take photo from camera in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera

In my `Fragment` I try to take picture from my camera but the `onActivityResult` of my `Fragment` is not called. After taking photo this `Fragment` is not showing and is switching to my first `Fragment`. In there any other way for capturing photos in a `Fragment`, or what am I doing wrong?

Here is my current code:

```
public void takePhoto() {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "Pic.jpg");
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                Uri.fromFile(photo));
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
        PhotosListFragment.this.startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 100:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
                getActivity().getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
                Bitmap bitmap;
                try {
                     bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                     .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                    viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), selectedImage.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried your code its working fine dude. I changed

```
PhotosListFragment.this.startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

to

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

which after taking the picture, returning back to same activity.

I think both of your fragments are on same activity.

if that is the situation, I suggest you to create a new activity and put the new fragment in there.

Comment: IS that onActivityResult on the fragment or activity?

Comment: my onActivityResult is not trigered. i put both of these methods inside my fragment. is there anything else i should do?

Comment: The onActivityResult is triggered in the activity which called the fragment

Answer (score 23):

Hope this will help you:

```
public class CameraImage extends Fragment {

    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1888;
    Button button;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_image,
                container, false);

        button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,
                        CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

            }
        });

        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                // convert byte array to Bitmap

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0,
                        byteArray.length);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
        }        
    }    
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, exactly what I wanted! This only returns the thumbnail though.

Comment: @user2630955 I have used your code and its not completely working. I am not able to view the image taken from camera. Can you please help me, I stuck from past 2 days on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

For Fragment this is simplest solution:

```
cameraIamgeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            getActivity().startActivityFromFragment(PlaceOrderFragment.this, cameraIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
   // super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            /*
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            // convert byte array to Bitmap

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0,
                    byteArray.length);
            */

            cameraIamgeView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        }
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), e+"Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```